# Is a Macintosh file a stationery pad?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file

Is there a sanctioned, non-deprecated way to detect whether an OS X file is or is not a stationery pad?

As far as I can determine, none of the NSFileManager methods provide an isStationery key, and the old FSpGetFInfo() method is, of course, deprecated.

Comment: FWIW, `FSGetCatalogInfo` is newer than `FSpGetFInfo`, but is also deprecated as of 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea that's probably unsanctioned, but not deprecated, so I don't know if it will make you happy.  It appears that the Finder attributes (`FileInfo` and `ExtendedFileInfo` structures) are stored in a 32-byte extended attribute named "com.apple.FinderInfo".  You could use the `getxattr` or `fgetxattr` function to read that.